# change background of an ImageView (the old image stays there!)

Tags: android

how can I change the background of an ImageView from java? I have an ImageView and at a certain point I need to change the image that it displays (set in the styles). I tried to do it like this:

```
placeHolder.setImageDrawable(myDrawb);
```

but it looks like the old image remains there and it is partially covered but the new one (which in my case has different shape).

hope you guys can help!

cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to touch the XML to use src instead of background!

An ImageView can display two drawables! One in the background and other in the foreground.
It seems that you are always changing the background image.

Instead of `setBackgroundResource(resId)` use `setImageResource(resId)` to change the foreground image!

Comment: sometimes the best answers are at the bottom :)

Answer (score 3):

Clear the background image with:

```
placeHolder.setBackgroundResource( 0 );
```

Comment: yes! that was it! so basically the android doesnt authomatically substitute the old with the new one ... it stacks them up unless you use setBackgroundResource. very usefull thanks

Comment: The background is independent of the content.  You are setting the content with setImageDrawable but leaving the background.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you should set the `Src` of the `ImageView` in xml instead of setting the `Background`.  I think this is the "right" way anyhow.

Comment: I cant touch the XML! I load images from the web and I need to chuck them in their placeholders when the download of the image is finished

Comment: this answer should be down voted as no link with question being asked here

Comment: @Sameer no, this is a useful answer. Though the owner have no use of this answer, but the others reading this can use this answer. In-fact, this answer helped me a lot